# align different image ridimension and delete margin

Tags: html, css

I should like know how I can fix different image alignment and remove margin.  I want to align items in the center but there is a part of iamge that I think is margin that I can't remove. The part I want remove is the orange zone

[image: IMG PROBLEM]

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content__row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.content__img {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 0%;
}

.content__a {
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.content__p {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(39, 39, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content__row">
    <a class="content__a" href="#">
      <img class="content__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x600" alt="">
      <p class="content__p">COMPILARE
        <br>
        <span class="content__span">730?</span>
      </p>
    </a>
    <a class="content__a" href="#">
      <img class="content__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x600" alt="">
      <p class="content__p">CALCOLARE
        <br>
        <span class="content__span">L'ISEE?</span>
      </p>
    </a>
    <a class="content__a" href="#">
      <img class="content__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x600" alt="">
      <p class="content__p">CALCOLARE
        <br>
        <span class="content__span">L'ISEE?</span>
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have `width: 80%`?

Comment: @aloisdg they're taking up 80% of the .content__a boxes. But I agree - unnecessary  - just make the a's the right size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically you've given your `<a>`'s a width of 30%, and there's no justify-content property on that flexbox (.content__row), so there's 10% left over on the right. Add `justify-content: space-between; (or around)` into your .column__row class.

Some comments:

I'm not sure why you're adding `flex` onto your images. If you turn your `<a>`'s into column flexboxes then you'll get rid of the 'space' character between your image and `<p>` tags (a common problem).

Look into adding the `object-fit: cover;` property onto your images, then you can resize them without worrying about the images distorting.

Answer (score 0):

Removed so many unnecessary things from CSS and added a couple.
Basically, see the comments in CSS

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content__row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 20px; /* add */
}

.content__a {
  text-decoration: none;
  flex: 1;
}

.content__img {
  height: 200px;     /* add */
  width: 100%;       /* add */
  object-fit: cover; /* add */
}

.content__p {
  text-align: center;
  font: 900 normal 1rem/1.5 Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content__row">
    <a class="content__a" href="#">
      <img class="content__img" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="">
      <p class="content__p">COMPILARE<br><span class="content__span">730?</span></p>
    </a>
    <a class="content__a" href="#">
      <img class="content__img" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="">
      <p class="content__p">CALCOLARE<br><span class="content__span">L'ISEE?</span></p>
    </a>
    <a class="content__a" href="#">
      <img class="content__img" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="">
      <p class="content__p">CALCOLARE<br><span class="content__span">L'ISEE?</span></p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Couple is css issue exist.

- Remove `width: 80%;` from `.content__p`. Because this will restrict the width of the p tage.
- For `.content__img` remove `width: 80%;` if you need full width image. If you are using `width: 80%;`, then add `margin: 0 auto;` to the same, this will add equal space at left and right of the image.
- `.content__img` I have removed `height: 90%;`. It looks odd with restricted height (Not mandatory, add if needed).
- From `.content` remove `padding: 20px;`. This will creeate unwanted horizontal scroll in the page.
- For `.content_a`, add `display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex: 1;` to avod the unwanted blank space in the right side of 3 elements.

**Working Fiddle**

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  /* Removiung padding, its creating unwanted scroll */
  /* padding: 20px; */
  width: 100%;
}

.content__row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.content__img {
  display: flex;
  /* Donot restrict height */
  /* height: 90%; */
  padding: 0%;
  /* Restrict width only if needed or else comment the below one */
  width: 80%;
  /* If you are having a width value, set margin to 0 auto to align image at center */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content__a {
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  /* Adding this because there is some blank space after 3 elements */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.content__p {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  /* Donot restrict width */
  /* width: 80%; */
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(39, 39, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="content__row">
  <a class="content__a" href="#">
    <img class="content__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="">
    <p class="content__p">
      COMPILARE
      <br>
      <span class="content__span">730?</span>
    </p>
  </a>
  <a class="content__a" href="#">
    <img class="content__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="">
    <p class="content__p">
      CALCOLARE
      <br>
      <span class="content__span">L'ISEE?</span>
    </p>
  </a>
  <a class="content__a" href="#">
    <img class="content__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="">
    <p class="content__p">
      CALCOLARE
      <br>
      <span class="content__span">L'ISEE?</span>
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why specifically this answer is downvoted? Please post the reason.